# How can I provide relative path to command line arguments in start option in C#

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have one directory folder where we are getting 100 files per day.

My program picks the files from the `IN` folder and puts them in the `Out` folder after processing them.

I am getting the issue that when I am giving the exact location in

> Project > Properties > DEBUG > START OPTION > COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS

(i.e "C:\Data\IN\File.txt") then the program executes successfully and finds the file, but when I provide the Location like "C:\Data\IN" it is not picking any file and is throwing the exception

> Could not find file 'C:\Data\In'. InnerException is Null.

The IN folder is getting 100 different files daily. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not a relative path, it is the absolute path of a directory instead of a file.

Comment: Thanks Oliver...So we can only provide Absolute path not relative path in Command line arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"C:\Data\IN" is not a relative path, it is an absolute path to the directory containing the files. You can get the files like this from an absolute directory path:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Data\IN", "*.txt");
```

---

If you only know the path of the directory relative to the EXE you can get the absolute path like this:

```
string dir = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"Data\IN");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Directory.GetFiles() static class to get a list of files to process.  The Microsoft Documentation has a useful example.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx